# Open scraped clickable button in a new tab in Python + Selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, tabs

I'm trying to, after scraping the link I want to follow, open it in a new tab. I've tried several ways but to no avail. My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser=webdriver.Chrome()
urlbet='https://www.bet365.es/?&cb=103265469#/HO/'

browser.get(urlbet)

sport=WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="dv1"]/a')))

sport.click()

login = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'hm-Login')))

fields = login.find_elements_by_css_selector('.hm-Login_InputField')
button = login.find_element_by_css_selector('.hm-Login_LoginBtn')

user='my_user'
passw='my_pass'
fields[0].send_keys(user)
fields[1].click()
fields[2].send_keys(passw)
button.click()
```

With all that, I log in my account and arrive at my desired web page.

```
trial=WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[contains(text(), "Baloncesto")]')))
```

And here, where I should open that button in a new tab, like right click "open on a new tab", I am not able. I've tried the following:

```
trial.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
```

and

```
trial.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.SHIFT + Keys.RETURN)
```

both times what I get is:

```
WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element
(Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.113)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 
(e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

I'm running python on Windows 7, webdriver Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more parsing, I came to the conclusion that this website does not offer the option of right click, open on a new tab, so, even though <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + Click should work, in reality, what it does is like a left button click, but not because of the code, but because the web responds that way to this shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying with `trial.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')` and `trial.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.SHIFT + Keys.RETURN)` try with `action_chains` as follows :

```
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
action = ActionChains(driver)
elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Gmail")
action\
    .move_to_element(elem)\
    .key_down(Keys.SHIFT)\
    .click(elem)\
    .key_up(Keys.SHIFT)\
    .perform()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. While it does load the page, it does it on the same tab, not in a new one.